# Create Seamless Video and Crop Video in one command

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a ffmpeg command that convert a video for seamless loop. But now i want to crop Video as well in same command.
is there any solution to do crop video 720x720 in same command

--Seamless Commmand--

ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]split[body][pre];[pre]trim=duration=1,format=yuva420p,fade=d=1:alpha=1,setpts=PTS+(28/TB)[jt];[body]trim=1,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[main];[main][jt]overlay -c:v libx264  -strict experimental out.mp4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `[0:v]split[body][pre]` to `[0:v]crop=720:720,split[body][pre]`